# Which ORM library/jar provides @columnAnnotation to connect with mongodb in java? Is it deprectaed? If yes. whats the alternative?

Tags: java, mongodb, orm, mapping

I am trying to build an old project which uses a jar (namely db.mongo.orm.jar) to provide Object relational mapping. I am aware of different ORM options available (listed at mongodb site) and have googled a lot before heading to stackoverflow. I am looking for a replacement to '@columnAnnotation' that i can use without any/much changes to the code. A sample of the current usage code snippet is like:

```
@XmlTransient
@ColumnAnnotation("_id")
protected ObjectId id;
public static final String FIELD_ID = "_id";

@XmlElement(name="id")
@ColumnAnnotation(isLoadFromDBObj = false, isSaveToDBObj = false)
protected String idString;
```

Some more usage snippet:

```
boolean flag = true;
ColumnAnnotation anno = field.getAnnotation(ColumnAnnotation.class);
if (anno != null) {
    flag = anno.isLoadFromDBObj();
}
```

Please suggest which ORM supports such properties and/or what can be used as a replacement to build this code.

Comment: Have you tried googling "[mongodb orm java](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+orm+java)"?

Comment: Yes. But none of the ORMs comply with the above syntax. Or to be specific have '@columnAnnotation' as a valid identifier. Probably it has been depricated. I am looking for the possible replacement (like '@column', etc.) that fits in-place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this by using `javax.persistence` package.
I replaced @columnAnnotation with @column (from javax.persistence.Column) and it fit in well. Although I had to vigilantly update some methods on the effected fields but all's well that ends well. Worked!